# Autofac register multiple decorators of multiple services

Tags: c#, autofac

I have the following services in my application:

```
public interface IDecorableService
{

}

public interface IServiceDecorator
{

}

public interface ICommentService
{
   Task<Comment> AddAsync(Comment comment);
}

public class CommentService : ICommentService, IDecorableService
{
   public async Task<Comment> AddAsync(Comment comment)
   {
      //some code
   }
}

[DecorationOrder(Order = 1)]
public class EventLoggingCommentService : ICommentService, IServiceDecorator
{
   private readonly ICommentService _commentService;

   private readonly IEventLoggerService _eventLoggerService;

   public EventLoggingCommentService(ICommentService commentService, IEventLoggerService eventLoggerService)
   {
      _commentService = commentService;
      _eventLoggerService = eventLoggerService;
   }

   public async Task<Comment> Add(Comment comment)
   {
      comment = await _commentService.AddAsync(comment);
      //log comment added event by eventLogService
      return comment;
   }
}

[DecorationOrder(Order = 2)]
public class NotificationCommentService : ICommentService, IServiceDecorator
{
   private readonly ICommentService _commentService;

   private readonly INotificationService _notificationService;

   public NotificationCommentService(ICommentService commentService, INotificationService notificationService)
   {
      _commentService = commentService;
      _notificationService = notificationService;
   }

   public async Task<Comment> Add(Comment comment)
   {
      comment = await _commentService.AddAsync(comment);
      //send notifications about comment by notificationService
      return comment;
   }
}
```

I also have some services which are similar to the CommentService (for example, PostService) and some services which not to be decorated.

I'm using Autofac and I need to register decorators for each service which need to be decorated (in the specified order) and register other services as self. I don't know. how many services need to be decorated.

I tried to do the following:

```
public class BusinessLayerModule : Module
{
   private readonly object[] _tags;

   private readonly string[] _skippingInterfaces = new string[]
   {
      nameof(IDecorableService),
      nameof(IDecoratedService)
   };

   public BusinessLayerModule(List<object> tags)
   {
      _tags = tags?.ToArray();
   }

   protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
   {
      Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

      //Registering non-decorable services
      builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.Name.EndsWith("Service") && !t.GetInterfaces().Any(x => _skippingIntefaces.Contains(x.Name)))
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(_tags);

      //Registering decorable services
      RegisterDecorators(builder, assembly, _tags);
   }

   private void RegisterDecorators(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly assembly, object[] tags)
   {
      //Getting all services which can be decorated
      List<Type> decorableServices = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.Name.EndsWith("Service")
                                                                      && t.GetInterface(nameof(IDecorableService)) != null
                                                                      && t.GetInterface(nameof(IServiceDecorator)) == null).ToList();


        foreach (Type type in decorableServices)
        {
            //Getting the base interface, for example, ICommentService
            Type baseType = type.GetInterfaces().First(x => x.Name.EndsWith(type.Name));

            MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(RegisterDecoratedService), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            MethodInfo gmi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(baseType, type);
            gmi.Invoke(this, new object[] {builder, assembly, baseType, type, tags});
        }
    }

   private void RegisterDecoratedService<TInterface, TImplementation>(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly assembly, Type baseType, Type implType, object[] tags)
    {
        //Getting all decorators of the service ordering by decoration order
        List<Type> decorators = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.Name.EndsWith("Service")
                                                               && t.GetInterface(baseType.Name) != null
                                                               && t.GetInterface(nameof(IServiceDecorator)) != null)
            .OrderBy(t =>
            {
                DecorationOrderAttribute order = t.GetCustomAttribute<DecorationOrderAttribute>();
                return order?.Order ?? 0;
            }).ToList();
        if (!decorators.Any())
        {
            //If there are no decorators, just registering base service
            builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>()
                .As<TInterface>()
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);
        }
        else
        {
            builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>()
                .Named<TInterface>(implType.FullName)
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);

            MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(RegisterDecorator), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            //Registering decorators
            for (int i = 0; i &lt; decorators.Count; i++)
            {
                MethodInfo gmi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(baseType, decorators[i]);
                gmi.Invoke(this, new object[] {builder, (i == 0) ? implType : decorators[i - 1], decorators[i], tags, i != decorators.Count - 1 });
            }
        }

    private void RegisterDecorator<TInterface, TDecorator>(ContainerBuilder builder, Type baseType, Type decoratorType, object[] tags, bool hasKey)
    {
       string decoratorName = decoratorType.FullName;

       builder.RegisterType<TDecorator>()
                .Named<TInterface>(decoratorName)
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);
       builder.RegisterDecorator<TInterface>((c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<TInterface>(decoratorName, TypedParameter.From(inner)), baseType.FullName, hasKey ? decoratorName : null)
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);
     }
}
}
```

When I make an API-request, I'm getting the following error:

Circular component dependency detected: MyApp.WebUI.Api.RatingsController -> MyApp.Logic.Services.RatingService -> MyApp.Logic.Handlers.Ratings.RatingHandler[] -> MyApp.Logic.Handlers.Ratings.CommentRatingHandler -> System.Object -> MyApp.Logic.Services.Decorated.WithEventLogging.CommentService -> System.Object.'.

I want to achieve the following
1. Each service which has decorated service need to be registered as a decorator (for example, CommentService->EventLoggingCommentService->NotificationCommentService, PostService->EventLoggingPostService->NotificationPostService,...)
2. Each service which hasn't decorated services need to be registered as self (for example, FavoritesObjectService).

Could you tell me, please, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you gotten it to work right without the decorators? Have you gotten it to work by registering just one service (like CommentService) and its decorators manually? Where are you registering the name tags (not scope tags, but named type tags) for the source types [as noted in the docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators)?

Comment: @TravisIllig, Yes. I registered only the base service CommentService and it works fine. I registered all decorators manually and everything works fine.

Comment: I updated the code, it works, but only if there is only one decorator. If I have two decorators, I'm getting the error above

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. I changed the RegisterDecoratedService as following:

```
private void RegisterDecorators(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly assembly, object[] tags)
{
   List<Type> decorableServices = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.Name.EndsWith("Service")
                                                                          && t.GetInterface(nameof(IDecorableService)) != null
                                                                          && t.GetInterface(nameof(IServiceDecorator)) == null).ToList();


   foreach (Type type in decorableServices)
   {
      Type baseType = type.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.EndsWith(type.Name));
      if (baseType == null)
      {
         builder.RegisterType(type)
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);
         break;
      }

      MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(RegisterDecoratedService), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
      MethodInfo gmi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(baseType, type);
      gmi.Invoke(this, new object[] {builder, assembly, tags});
   }
}



private void RegisterDecoratedService<TInterface, TImplementation>(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly assembly, object[] tags)
   {
      List<Type> decorators = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.Name.EndsWith("Service")
                                                                       && t.GetInterface(typeof(TInterface).Name) != null
                                                                       && t.GetInterface(nameof(IServiceDecorator)) != null)
                    .OrderBy(t =>
                    {
                        DecorationOrderAttribute order = t.GetCustomAttribute<DecorationOrderAttribute>();
                        return order?.Order ?? 0;
                    }).ToList();

      if (!decorators.Any())
      {
         builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>()
                .As<TInterface>()
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);
      }
      else
      {
         string implName = typeof(TImplementation).Name;

         builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>()
                .Named<TInterface>(implName)
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);

         for (int i = 0; i < decorators.Count; i++)
         {
            string decoratorKey = decorators[i].FullName;
            string fromKey = (i == 0) ? implName : $"{implName}Decorator{i}";
            string toKey = $"{implName}Decorator{i + 1}";

            builder.RegisterType(decorators[i])
                   .Named<TInterface>(decoratorKey)
                   .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);

            if (i != decorators.Count - 1)
            {
               builder.RegisterDecorator<TInterface>((c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<TInterface>(decoratorKey, TypedParameter.From(inner)), fromKey, toKey)
                                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);
             }
             else
             {
                 builder.RegisterDecorator<TInterface>((c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<TInterface>(decoratorKey, TypedParameter.From(inner)), fromKey)
                                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Now it works for 2 and 3 decorators.